# Why "('a' in arr) in arr" != "'a' in arr in arr"?

Tags: python, operators

Why is `('a' in arr) in arr` != `'a' in arr in arr`?

```
arr = [1, True, 'a', 2]
print(('a' in arr) in arr)  # -> True
print('a' in arr in arr)  # -> False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Section 6.10 of the Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) discusses comparison operators and comparison chaining. `in` is considered a comparison operator, and so behaves the same as `<`, etc. Without parentheses for explicit grouping, `x OP1 y OP2 z`is equivalent to `x OP1 y and y OP2 z` for any two comparison operators.

This means that

```
'a' in arr in arr
```

without parentheses, is equivalent to

```
'a' in arr and arr in arr
```

`arr` is not an element of itself, so the expression is `False.`

Parentheses disable chaining, so

```
('a' in arr) in arr
```

is evaluated like any other nested expression. `'a' in arr` is evaluated first to the value `True`, then `True in arr` is evaluated to also produce `True`.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but I think that `in` is like any binary operator, so just like you have `a < b < c` equivalent to `(a < b) and (b < c)` , you will have

```
a in b in c
```

equivalent to

```
(a in b) and (b in c)
```

`'a' in arr` is True, but `arr in arr` is False, that's why you have a `False` value.

Comment: Not binary operators in general, only comparison operators.

Comment: For testing: for a list `arr2 = [[1, True, 'a', 2], [1, 2, 3]]` printing `print('a' in arr in arr2)` returns `True`, behaves like expected with your explanation

Comment: @chepner: true, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given `arr=[1,True,'a',2]`,

Decoding first expression: `('a' in arr) in arr`,

*step-by-step*

- `('a' in arr) in arr` evaluates to
- `(True) in [1,True,'a',2]` evaluates to
- `True`

Decoding second expression: `('a' in arr in arr)`

*step-by-step*

- `('a' in arr in arr)` This is equivalent to
- `('a' in arr and arr in arr)` which evaluates to
- `(True and False)` which   evaluates to
- `(False)`

More on: Precedence and associative nature https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity

Comment: I corrected it. Take a look